# error al crear un nuevo proyecto angular unexpected end of JSON

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

Estoy creando un nuevo proyecto con Angular y me muestra el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el proyecto se crea de esta forma, si ven la carpeta node_modules no aparece:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Antes de hacer esta pregunta leí que recomendaban actualizar la versión de angular cli y también node.

mis versiones son:

node- v:  10.16.1
ng version: 8.3.0

antes de este proyecto cree otro hace un tiempo y no tuve problema alguno, por que pasa esto?

1. Es estricatemente necesario actualzar angular CLI y node?
2. Si las actualiza me va a afectar el otro proyecto que tengo? esto último es que lo más me preocupa ya que no quiero dañar el otro proyecto.

Gracias de antemano al que me pueda ayudar,

Saludos!

Comment: tienes git instalado

Comment: como creaste el proyecto? con el comando ng new [name_project] ?

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomiendo instalar **Node Version Manager para Windows** NVM, si no quieres actualizar tu node global es muy buena opción [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) aquí tienes los pasos, lo que hace nvm es que puedes usar varias versiones de node en el mismo ambiente sin afectar a otros desarrollos que estan en versiones previas, revisa si tienes instalado git como te mencionaron anteriormente.